# top, bottom, right, left values not working as flex container is set as justify-content: center

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make the 'rating-block' to be positioned at the bottom-right side of 'card'. But these values don't work as its container has justify-content centre so it will force it in the centre. Is there a better way to position it to the bottom right?

```css
.card {
    width: 210px;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative
}

.card-img {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.rating-block {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    top: 100px;
}

.rating {
    margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
        <div class="rating-block">
            <p class="rating">4.5</p>
        </div>

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding top: 185px; and left: 115px; to the .rating-block class

```css
.card {
    width: 210px;
    height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative
}

.card-img {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    
}

.rating-block {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 10px;
    top: 185px;
    left: 115px;
}

.rating {
    margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="card">
        <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
        <div class="rating-block">
            <p class="rating">4.5</p>
        </div>

    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tyy. it worked. Btw, how do u get .rating-block to start from .card and not the whole body. Cause if you set the top 0px, it goes all the way to the top of the body and not the .card . I already set position relative to .card but its still not working. @Rizeen

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a suggestion for css variables here as if you change the size of your div, it will automatically position the pill. Also consider using ::before as this cuts out a bit of markup too.

```css
.card {
  --card-width: 210px;
  --card-height: 250px;
  --image-scale: 0.5;
  width: var(--card-width);
  height: var(--card-height);
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-img {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100% * var(--image-scale));
}

.card::before {
  content: attr(data-rating);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transform: translate(calc(0.5 * var(--card-width) * var(--image-scale)), calc(0.5 * var(--card-height) * var(--image-scale) + 1rem));
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-rating="4.5">
  <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41rsAHrKw1L._AC_SY580_.jpg" alt="card-1" class="card-img">
</div>
```